# Get Change type in delta Events in Microsoft Graph Api

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, exchangewebservices, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-teams, microsoft-graph-calendar

I am migrating from EWS to Microsoft graph and having problem in replacing flow "ExchangeService.syncFolderItems".

```
ChangeCollection<ItemChange> changedItems = exchangeService.syncFolderItems(calendarFolder.getId(),
FirstClassProperties, null, 512, NormalItems, syncState);
```

This gives me all the changes since last sync state with change type.
Now I need to replace this with Microsoft graph.

I saw Get delta api in Microsoft graph and also how to call it recursively using stale token. My query is, Get delta api is not returning the change Item type. Could someone suggest me the best way to implement this in Microsoft graph? Maybe the Apis that I need to use for this?

Note:This flow will be called by my service to get changes after fixed interval of time. Also I saw subscriptions ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/subscription?view=graph-rest-1.0 )but not sure that could be used in my case as my service will be making a call to get changes for a meeting room after a fixed scheduled interval of time.

I am stuck here. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deleted events will have a @removed property and only provide the id of the object as denoted here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/delta-query-overview#resource-representation-in-the-delta-query-response

Updated objects will only include the updated properties and added objects should include all the data available. It's up to the 3rd party application (your app) to maintain a state on it's side to be able to differentiate between updated and created objects when using Delta queries.

Combining webhooks with Delta to trigger the sync instead of relying on a timer is a good approach to provide an end user experience that feels more real time

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but Webhooks will require a separate server to be maintained from I read about which is not possible in my case. I need to  rely on delta query and update will happen once the scheduled job runs and picks up all the changes. could you help me with how recurring master should be handled in case of delta query??  Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not how stack overflow works, ask one precise and concise question to get an answer. Don't hesitate to break a specific problem in multiple more generic questions.

Comment: Thnks @baywet . I have posted a separate query for the same. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62625566/how-to-handle-recurring-master-events-using-microsoft-delta-queries

Comment: great! don't forget to mark this one as answered :)