# How to handle deleted Recurring master events using Microsoft delta queries

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, exchangewebservices, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-teams, microsoft-graph-calendar

I am trying to move from EWS to Microsoft graph and facing problem while implementing syncFolderItems flow.

I need to track and update changes of all created, modified and deleted events using Microsoft graph apis.

I went through Microsoft documentation and found they have delta Api which returns only the changes which occurred from last sync. But I am not sure how recurring events should be handled using delta queries api.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The current behavior is that only the master event (the one with the recurring pattern) will show up in the delta feed, not the other instances. Only instances that have been updated will then show up in the delta feed.

You would need to use the calendar view API to get all the occurrences of a specific master event (with a recurrence pattern) you see in the delta feed.

Additionally you can ask for recurring events instances to be added to the delta feed on [Microsoft Graph uservoice](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com).